# How to minimize this DFA with already merged states?

Tags: finite-automata

The original nondeterministic FSA I have is:

[image: NDFA]

After converting this to a DFA I get:

[image: DFA]

If I use the Myhill-Nerode theorem on the current DFA, I get all pairs marked, so this is already minimized. But I think this is incorrect.

I want to minimize this DFA. How should I do this using the Myhill-Nerode theorem, since some of the states are merged already?

Comment: "I think this is incorrect." Why?

Comment: @Apass.Jack The question asks for minimization of the DFA, so I didn't think that it would already be minimized.

Comment: "I didn't think that it would already be minimized." **Why?** What did you mean by "I get all pairs marked, **so** this is already minimized."? Why did you say "so"?

Answer (score 1):

After inputs $\epsilon$, $a$, $ab$, $abc$, $abca$ we must be in five different states because appending $b$ to one of these leads to an accept only for $abca$, appending nothing to any of the others leads to an accept only for $abc$, appending $c$ leads to an accept only for $ab$, appending $bc$ to any of the remaining only for $a$.

A bit more formally, given a string $\alpha$, we note in a 4-tuple whether $\alpha$, $\alpha b$, $\alpha c$, $\alpha bc$ are accepted. For $\alpha = \epsilon, a,ab,abc,abca$, these 4-tuples are $(0,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,0,1)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, $(1,0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0,1)$, hence all distintc. This is only possible if these $\alpha$ correspond to differnt states.