# Minimization of DFA 3 inputs Table Filling Method

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I do understand how minimization of DFA works where there are 2 words lets say $\{a, b\}$. However, I came across this minimization of a DFA over  the language of $\{a, b, c\}$ $\left(\Sigma, \{q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4\}, \{(q_0, a, q_1), (q_1, a, q_1), (q_1, b, q_2), (q_2, c, q_3), (q_3, a, q_4), (q_4, a, q_4), (q_4,b,q_2)\}, q_0, \{q_3, q_4\}\right)$

When filling up the table I get some states that brake just because I cannot make a transition from $q_3$ with b. 
Then if we investigate the set $\{q_4, q_3\}$ in order to see if we can mark it in the table it gives us a broken transition from $q_3$ with $b$ so it looks like $\{q_4, q_3\}$ with $b$ transition $\{q_2, ? \}$ in this case, do we mark $\{q_4, q_3\}$ in the table or not and why?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: A DFA should define a transition for each state (i.e., $q_0,q_1,...,q_4$) and each symbol (i.e., $a,b,c$). Are you sure you mean "DFA"?

Comment: @phan801 The undefined transitions probably trigger an immediate reject response by the DFA (or, alternatively, they land in a "trash" state in which all words are rejected).

Comment: I wasn't sure when they land in a "trash" state If I have to accept or reject it. It seems that this example is already a Minimised DFA and it was a bit tricky to prove that.

Comment: @phan801 This is completely dependant on your definition. I was taught (and always saw in the literature) that DFAs with such missing transitions just reject the word when such a case happens. Moreover, your definition of DFAs is often called a complete DFA.

Comment: @wazdra I undersatnd I was wrong. I didn't delete the comment after dkaeae's explanation in case anybody else had the same misconception.

Comment: A graphic representation of the DFA is given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abAle.png), also shown at question [How to minimize this DFA with already merged states?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104342/how-to-minimize-this-dfa-with-already-merged-states).